# Red dead redemption GOTY vs. undead nightmare DLC

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I have already purchased Red Dead Redemption on Xbox 360, and played through it without any DLC content. 
I was wondering the GOTY edition has extra add-on content compared to just buying the Undead Nightmare DLC.

Answer (score 0):

No I dont think it comes with anything extra (I've owned both)